# Recommend Method to Display message to user

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile, template10

Loving Template10, but I'm wondering what the preferred method is to display a message to the user for a phone based app.  For example in the Windows Phone app I'm writing I want to let the user know that I was unable to get their location (maybe they are in an elevator and unable to get a GPS reading), so we can't do some calculations and display some results without that location.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a classic `MessageDialog`. If you want something less "blocking", just show a toast, there is a helper to do it in the Coding4Fun toolkit.

Comment: Toasts work not to bad but how do I keep them out of the Action Center as this is just a quick message sort of thing and don't have any lasting significance to be found it or kept in the Action Center.

Comment: Use the Coding4Fun solution, it looks like a toast but it is not a real toast, it is faked.

Comment: Does the Coding4Fun solution work with Windows 10?  I added the Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls to my project, and then this code which is triggered off a menu item for testing

Comment: Does the Coding4Fun solution work with Windows 10?  I added the Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls 

private static ToastPrompt GetBasicToast(string t, string m)
        {
            return new ToastPrompt
            {
                Title = t,
                Message = m
            };
        }

        public void DisplayToast()
        {
            var toast = GetBasicToast("Title", "My Message");

            toast.Show();
        }

I get {"The parameter is incorrect.\r\n\r\nreference"} Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: should, use ToastPrompt from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls/

Comment: I created the most basic Template10 project added the Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls and a button to create a send a toast and got  the error message, so I thinking there might be a problem.  I wonder if its around some of the adaptive stuff now in Windows10 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Views.Busy in the samples, we have a built-in option already available

Comment: Thanks!  When I was looking at Template10 on Git I could see this https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/BusyIndicatorControl but when I downloaded the zip and looked for that sample, but I couldn't find it, but found it elsewhere in the samples.